# Cannot retrieve data from .csv file

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to read two values from a comma delimited .csv file.
Here is my test.csv:

```
14,0.49
```

After doing some research, I found this [post](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/334515/reading-comma-separated-values-with-fscanf) which seems to mimic my problem. Here is my attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  float value_a;
  float value_b;

  FILE *fp = fopen("test.csv", "r");

  char buffer_a[255];
  char buffer_b[255];

  fscanf(fp, "%s%*c%s", buffer_a, buffer_b);

  value_a = atof(buffer_a);
  value_b = atof(buffer_b);

  printf("value_a is %f", value_a);
  printf("value_b is %f", value_b);

  fclose(fp);
}
```

output:

```
value_a is 14.000000
value_b is 0.000000
```

My program (**fscanf()** in particular) is successfully retriveing 14 and then **atof()** converts it to a float as I expected, but the second number is just retrieved as 0.0.

Why is the second value after the comma not being retrieved by **fscanf**?

Thanks!

Comment: ... and check the return value from `fscant` to ensure that it has been successful

Comment: Please using google with `site:stackoverflow.com` in the search string for future research. There are hundreds of posts about fscanf for csv - and for how it doesn't even work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As user3121023 points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131749/cannot-retrieve-data-from-csv-file#comment100779760_57131749)

> `%`s skips leading whitespace, scans non-whitespace and stops on whitespace. The first `%s` scans `14,0.49` into `buffer_a`.

Here's one way to solve it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float value_a;
    float value_b;

    FILE *fp = fopen("test.csv", "r");
    if (!fp)
    {
        perror("Could not open file");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (fscanf(fp, "%f,%f", &value_a, &value_b) != 2)
    {
        perror("Could not read the file");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("value_a is %f\n", value_a);
    printf("value_b is %f\n", value_b);

    fclose(fp);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
value_a is 14.000000
value_b is 0.490000
```

Comment: Thanks! Why is **fscanf(fp, "%f,%f", &value_a, &value_b) != 2**? In C, zero means false right?

Comment: @0x76syoa8p Because The return value is the number of receiving arguments successfully assigned, which must be 2 in our case, anything else means some kind of error/mismatching,